# The meaning of "inframarginal" in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with the meaning the word  "inframarginal" in the following sentence:

> A WDR could launch and help focus the debate. It
>   could also initiate a parallel debate on the future role of the state and of
>   global governance arrangements in a world where inframarginal discussions
>   will be made—by the state—on where and how people can live in
>   order to fit into the global budget of resources and global public goods.

Comment: Did you check the meaning of the prefix *infra-*?

Answer (score 2):

***Inframarginal*** means within or beneath the margins. Precisely what that means depends on context, indeed, but you haven't given enough context for us to be able to help more. What are the margins in question? There's a medical meaning, an entomological meaning, and an economic meaning, at the very least. Perhaps this is the economic meaning, which this [economic terminology glossary](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~alandear/glossary/i.html) might help with.